# How can I get the file from local server on my intranet instead of internet in hook install

Tags: juju

I try to create hook--> install for my charm ( home-made) , I have the Tar.
As I see i can get the tar from internet link by wget and then save it on local hard.

But if I went to get same file from local servers on intranet, what solution you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the hook to grab it from a local server, just use it's internal address instead of a public-facing internet one.

Another solution, which is probably more robust is to include the tarball in the charm itself. Do something like create a `files/` directory, put the tarball in there, and then have the install hook install from there.

This will allow the charm to deploy even if the server on the intranet is unreachable.